# Android custom ListView creation

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I created my own ListView but there is a problem that  for my own list is dont work the click event handler(onListItemClick).

Source code:

***MainActivity.java***

```
    package com.example.notes;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

        public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "Date";
        public static final String EXTRA_SHORT = "ShortMessage";
        public static final String EXTRA_LONG = "LongMessage";

        private ArrayList<NoteItem> list;

        //String [] names = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        //ArrayAdapter<String> my = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);


        list = new ArrayList<NoteItem>();

        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.notes);

            while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("note")) {
                    list.add(new NoteItem(parser.getAttributeValue(0), parser.getAttributeValue(1), parser.getAttributeValue(2)));
                }
                parser.next();
            }
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.errMsg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }


        NoteArrayAdapter adapter = new NoteArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.note, list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        Toast.makeText(this, "oncreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //setListAdapter(my);

    }



    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Log.d("ListItem", "LIST ITEM CLICKED!!!");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

***NoteArrayAdapter.java***

```
package com.example.notes;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NoteArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> {

    private Context context;
    private List<NoteItem> list;

    public NoteArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            List<NoteItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.list = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note, parent, false);
        }



            TextView textDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
            TextView textShort = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textShort);

            textDate.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
            textShort.setText(list.get(position).getShortMessage());

            return rowView;

            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }
    }
```

***NoteItem.java***

```
package com.example.notes;

public class NoteItem {

    private String date;
    private String shortMessage;
    private String longMessage;

    public NoteItem(String date, String shortMessage, String longMessage) {
        this.date = date;
        this.shortMessage = shortMessage;
        this.longMessage = longMessage;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getShortMessage() {
        return shortMessage;
    }

    public String getLongMessage() {
        return longMessage;
    }

}
```

***note.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/editButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDate"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test"
            android:gravity="left|center"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textShort"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Test"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

***notes.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Notes>

    <note
        date="26.08.1991"
        shortMessage="birthday"
        longMessage="Maxim Lazarenko birthday"/>

    <note
        date="04.01.1988"
        shortMessage="birthday"
        longMessage="Svetlana Rudaya birthday"/>

    <note
        date="26.08.1991"
        shortMessage="birthday"
        longMessage="Maxim Lazarenko birthday"/>

    <note
        date="04.01.1988"
        shortMessage="birthday"
        longMessage="Svetlana Rudaya birthday"/>

    <note
        date="26.08.1991"
        shortMessage="birthday"
        longMessage="Maxim Lazarenko birthday"/>

    <note
        date="04.01.1988"
        shortMessage="birthday"
        longMessage="Svetlana Rudaya birthday"/>

    <note
        date="26.08.1991"
        shortMessage="birthday"
        longMessage="Maxim Lazarenko birthday"/>

    <note
        date="04.01.1988"
        shortMessage="birthday"
        longMessage="Svetlana Rudaya birthday"/>

</Notes>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what was expected and what went wrong?

Comment: By clicking on the item it should pop-up message handler but does not work as if ignored

Comment: Not fire the click event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
    @Override
     protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked row " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

For More Details Go to this link :

[Android ListActivity row click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713539/android-listactivity-row-click)

Comment: It doesn't need because I use ListActivity

Comment: @lazexe check it out my edited answer. Does it works for you??

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:focusable="false"` for all clickable components in your note.xml.
You are not getting callback to onListItemClick(), as these components(ImageButton) is taking the click event.
Hope this helps.